# Comparing names given method header?

Tags: java

Given the header:

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName)
```

I'm supposed to compare two name objects for equality. What I have right now is:

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName){
    return (name1.equalsIgnoreCase(name2));
}
```

However, I get an  identifier expected error. I think it would work if I change the parameters but the assignment asks that I use that header. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the name constructor:

```
public Name (String first, String middle, String last){ 
firstName = first; 
middleName = middle; 
lastName = last; 
}
```

Comment: What is `Name`? Does it have an `equalsIgnoreCase` method?

Comment: where is name1 and name2 initialized? better yet are they initialized anywhere?

Comment: Looks like you want to use otherName inside the method since you are passing it in.

Comment: I have the feeling you might have something wrong with that header. And it's clear you need to go back to basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get " get an identifier expected error." because `name1` and `name2` are defined. Inside equals method you pass another object so refer it as `otherName` and the object itself is accessible as `this`.

Try

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName) {
    return (otherName.equalsIgnoreCase(this));
}
```

or

```
 public boolean equals(Name otherName) {
    return (equalsIgnoreCase(otherName));
}
```

Of course, you should have `equalsIgnoreCase` implemented for `Name` class.

Comment: No need to add the extra nullcheck: `this.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName)`.  However, this assumes that `Name` has an `equalsIgnoreCase` method.  More likely, `Name` has a string field which needs to be compared for equality here, but OP hasn't included anything about a field or method with such information.

Comment: We don't know how `equalsIgnoreCase` is implemented in this class, so we can't say that it will necessarily prevent nullpointerexceptions if `null` is passed as the parameter (so the null check isn't necessarily useless). Either way, it's really hard to answer this question with only the information given.

Comment: @A.R.S., agree but I believe this code is useful to OP unless he updates the question giving us more details.

Comment: Sorry, looking at my previous questions, it seems that I add too much unnecessary information. This time, I didn't add enough.

 public boolean equals(Name otherName){
  return this.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName);
 }

is what it looks like now but equalsIgnoreCase gives me a cannot find symbol error so I guess I implemented it wrong.

Comment: @user1740066, please, show us how Name is implemented. And I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @user1740066, update it in the question and delete code from comments.

Comment: still we dont see how you've implemented `equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: I think at this point it's better to start a new question regarding this, this is pretty old, no?

Unless of course, this is frowned upon?