# Comparing names given method header? v2

Tags: java

Well, the other question was pretty old and I figured it was unlikely more people were gonna stumble upon it and read/answer it so here goes: 
Given the header:

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName)
```

I'm supposed to compare two name objects for equality. What I have right now is:

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName){
        return (otherName.equalsIgnoreCase(this));
    }
```

as suggested by someone in the previous thread.

However, I am getting a cannot find symbol error.

Here is the rest of my code to be nitpicked. Forgive me for its sloppiness and whatnot, I'm not coding well at all tonight.

Name.java:

```
public class Name{
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name (String first, String middle, String last){
        firstName = first;
        middleName = middle;
        lastName = last;
    }

    public String getFirst(){
    return firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddle(){
        return middleName;
    }

    public String getLast(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public String firstMiddleLast(){
        return (firstName + middleName + lastName);
    }

    public String lastFirstMiddle(){
        return (lastName + ", " + middleName + firstName);      
    }

    public boolean equals(Name otherName){
        return (otherName.equalsIgnoreCase(this));
    }

    public String initials(){
        String initials = firstName.substring(0,1) + middleName.substring(0,1) + lastName.substring(0,1);
        initials.toUpperCase();
        return initials; 
    }

    public int length(){
        int sum = firstName.length() + middleName.length() + lastName.length();
        return sum;
    }
}
```

TestingNames.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestNames{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first name, middle name, and last name in that order for the first name object.");
    Name name = new Name(scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next());
    System.out.println("Enter the second name, middle name, and last name in that order for the first name object.");
    Name name2 = new Name(scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next());   

    System.out.println("Printing name in the order first name, middle name, last name");
    System.out.println(name.firstMiddleLast());
    System.out.println(name2.firstMiddleLast());

    System.out.println("Printing name in the order last name, first name, middle name");
    System.out.println(name.lastFirstMiddle());
    System.out.println(name2.lastFirstMiddle());

    System.out.println("Printing initials");
    System.out.println(name.initials());
    System.out.println(name2.initials());

    System.out.println("Printing name length");
    System.out.println(name.length());
    System.out.println(name2.length());

    System.out.println("Are these names equal?");
    System.out.println(name.equals(name2));



    }
}
```

Comment: Try `return (otherName.equalsIgnoreCase(this.firstName));`

Comment: Well my guess would be that `Name` doesn't declare `equalsIgnoreCase` (`String` does). Why are you overloading [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals\(java.lang.Object\)) anyway? Also, please provide a link to the previous question so we can get some context.

Comment: [Previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812821/comparing-names-given-method-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you donot have `equalsIgnoreCase` method implemented in class `Name` while you are using in:

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName){
    return (otherName.equalsIgnoreCase(this));
}
```

so error is bound to come.
you can try:

```
 public boolean equals(Name otherName){
    if(firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName.firstName) && middleName.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName.middleName) && lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName.lastName))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Alright, this is gonna be an idiotic question but please bear with me: What do you mean by it isn't implemented? I've only ever had to call the method and it'd work. Sorry

Comment: it works for `String` as it is implemented there. If you are using it you have to define this method like you are doing `equals` method. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName){
            return (otherName.getFirst().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName));
        }
```

> you are comparing object not String ...